# Failed processing format-parameters; Python 'maskedarray' cannot be converted to a MySQL type

Tags: python, arrays, gis, netcdf4, opendap

I'm still new to python linked to MySQL, and I'm getting a problem like below. are there any clues I should do? Here is my code:

```
import mysql.connector 
from netCDF4 import Dataset 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import cartopy.crs as ccrs 
import pyodbc
 
file = '182.16.248.173:8080/dods/INA-NWP/2021030100/2021030100-d02-asim' 
url = Dataset(file) rainc = url.variables['rainc'][7,0,:,:] 

con = mysql.connector.connect( host = "", user = "", password = "", db = "" ) 

dbcursor = con.cursor() 

sql = "INSERT INTO gis (id, name, var1) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
data = ("01", "2021030100", rainc) 
dbcursor.execute(sql, data) 
con.commit()
 
print("records inserted")
```

Comment: Kindly paste the code here

Comment: import mysql.connector
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import pyodbc

file = 'http://182.16.248.173:8080/dods/INA-NWP/2021030100/2021030100-d02-asim'
url = Dataset(file)

rainc = url.variables['rainc'][7,0,:,:]

con = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "",
    user = "",
    password = "",
    db = ""
)

dbcursor = con.cursor()
sql = "INSERT INTO gis (id, name, var1) VALUES (%s, %s, %s)"
data = ("01", "2021030100", rainc)

dbcursor.execute(sql, data)

con.commit()

print("records inserted")

Comment: Please [edit] the question and paste the code

Comment: @Sujay I've edited it

Comment: What is the error?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL doesn't accept arrays at all masked or otherwise. The error is simply reading back to you the data type you are sending, in this case a `maskedarray` in the form of `rainc`, and telling you that there is no equivalent MySQL data type, or that where you are sending it doesn't accept that data type.

This documentation about MySQL data types should clear it up:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/data-types.html

Comment: what data type do you think I should use for the data coming from here (182.16.248.173:8080/dods/INA-NWP/2021030100/2021030100-d02-asim) ?
because I have tried several data types but still not working

Comment: That all depends. Is this data being stored to be used by python at a later date or is it going to be pulled and displayed by JavaScript, ect. If you will only be using it in python you can pickle it and store it that way. If this is intended to be used as JavaScript you will likely want to convert it to JSON with python and then save it as a `VARCHAR`. For other applications you may have to break it up and store it in pieces.